# Duplicate declaration of same resource defined in separate classes

Tags: puppet

I have a class definition which requires the `build-essential` package:

```
class erlang($version = '17.3') {

  package { "build-essential": 
    ensure => installed
  }
  ...
}
```

Another class in a different module also requires the `build-essential` package:

```
class icu {

  package { "build-essential": 
    ensure => installed
  }
  ...
}
```

However, when I try to perform puppet apply, the error I receive is:

```
Error: Duplicate declaration: Package[build-essential] is already declared in file /vagrant/modules/erlang/manifests/init.pp:18; cannot redeclare at /vagrant/modules/libicu/manifests/init.pp:17 on node vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.home
```

I was expecting classes to encapsulate the resources they use but this doesn't seem to be the case?  How can I resolve this clash?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is common question when dealing with multiple modules.

There's a number of ways of doing this, the best practise is to modularise and allow the installation of build essential as a parameter:

```
class icu ($manage_buildessential = false){

  if ($manage_buildessential == true) {
   package { "build-essential": 
     ensure => installed
   }
 }
}
```

Then, where you want to include your ICU class:

```
class {'icu':
   manage_buildessential => 'false',
}
```

However, for a quick and dirty fix:

```
if ! defined(Package['build-essential']) {
    package { 'build-essential': ensure => installed }
}
```

Or if you have puppetlabs-stdlib module:

```
ensure_packages('build-essential')
```

Comment: Since I switched to `ensure_packages` my quality of life improved drastically. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you control both modules, you should write a third class (module) to manage the shared resource.

```
class build_essential {
    package { 'build-essential': ensure => installed }
}
```

Contexts that require the package just

```
include build_essential
```

#### Do not touch the defined() function with a 12" pole. There can be only pain down this road.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways as the other answers explain but this is another reliable way of doing it if you want to use the same resource multiple times.

Declare once and then realize it multiple times.. For example, Create a new virtual resource like this:

in modules/packages/manifests/init.pp

```
class packages {
  @package{ 'build-essential':
    ensure => installed
  }
}
```

Then, in your both classes, include the below lines to realize the above virtual resource

```
include packages
realize Package('build-essential')
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Martijn Heemels comment.
It looks like `ensure_packages` makes life match easier.

A nice example from this [cookbook](https://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/install-same-package-in-multiple-classes.html)
Challenge: You want to manage a package from multiple places.

```
# Assumes you've already installed the puppetlabs-stdlib module

class strace {
  notify { 'In strace': }
  ensure_packages(['build-essential'], { ensure => 'present' })
}

class debug_tools {
  # install lots of debug tools, and then strace
  notify { 'In debug_tools': }
  ensure_packages(['build-essential'], { ensure => 'present' })
}
```